# Contacts in Marshmallow (Samsung Galaxy S6)

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow

In 5.1.1, there was a list that was called *"frequently contacted"* in favorites. After upgrading to 6.0.1 that list is gone and doesn't appear again. Does anybody know anything about this?

Answer (score -3):

You just have to wipe cache and the problem is gone!

Comment: Apparently, it's OP self-answering their question. If possible, please expand the answer by explaining how to do to that. Otherwise, future readers might be confused to follow this answer.